# How to save to an INI file delphi

Tags: file, delphi, save, ini

I have buttons which when clicked store their caption in a TStringList

```
ChairList : TStringList;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
ChairList := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

An example of one button is:

```
procedure TForm1.Table17Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label1.Visible := false;
if (BottomPanel.Visible = false) then
begin
  Label1.Visible := true;

  LastClicked := 'Table 17';
  ChairList.Add(LastClicked);
```

But when I read the file I get no result back. I tested it by using a `ShowMessage` just to see if anything would be read and I just get a blank `ShowMessage`

The following code is the save procedure:

```
Procedure TForm1.SaveToFile(Const Filename : String);
Var
INI : TMemIniFile;

Procedure SaveReserve();
var
section : String;

Begin
  Section := 'Table';
  ini.writeString(Section, 'LastClickedID', LastClicked);
End;

begin
Ini := Tmeminifile.Create(filename);
ini.Clear;
try
SaveReserve();
Ini.UpdateFile;
finally
Ini.Free;
end;
end;
```

Then the next Procedure is the load file:

```
Procedure TForm1.LoadFile(const Filename : String);
var
INI : TMemInifile;
Sections : TStringList;
i : Integer;
LastClickedID : String;
Procedure LoadChair(Const Section: String);
Begin
  LastClickedID := INI.ReadString(Section, 'LastClickedID', LastClicked)
End;

Begin
ChairList.Clear;

INI := TMEMINIFILE.Create(Filename);
 Try
 Sections := TStringList.Create;
 Try
   Ini.ReadSections(Sections);
   for i := 0 to (Sections.Count - 1) do
   Begin
     if startstext('LastClickedID', Sections[I]) then
      begin
        LastClickedID := (copy(Sections[I], 12, MaxInt));

      end;
   End;
 Finally
  Sections.Free;
 End;
 Finally
 INI.Free;
end;
ShowTable(LastClickedID);
end;

ShowTable(LastClickedID); is just the part where i test it
```

How can i make it so it saves the caption and then when i load it up it shows any table caption saved?
I only need it to save the caption of an object selected. When the user selects a button it adds the caption to the stringlist which is then read to the ini file

Answer (score 5):

try this code!
**Procedure for write ini:**

```
procedure write_ini;
var
  ini:TIniFile;
begin
  ini:=TIniFile.Create('MainForm.ini');
  ini.WriteInteger('FORM', 'Top', MainForm.Top);
  ini.WriteInteger('FORM', 'Left', MainForm.Left);
  ini.WriteInteger('FORM', 'Width', MainForm.Width);
  ini.WriteInteger('FORM', 'Height', MainForm.Height);
  ini.WriteString('USER', 'Name', MainForm.userName.Text);
  ini.WriteInteger('USER','Pol', MainForm.Combo.ItemIndex);
  ini.Free;
end;
```

**Procedure for read ini:**

```
 procedure read_ini;
    var
     ini:TIniFile;
    begin
      ini:=TiniFile.Create('MainForm.ini');
      MainForm.Top:=ini.ReadInteger('FORM', 'Top', 0);
      MainForm.Left:=ini.ReadInteger('FORM', 'Left', 0);
      MainForm.Width:=ini.ReadInteger('FORM', 'Width', 226);
      MainForm.Height:=ini.ReadInteger('FORM', 'Height', 123);
      MainForm.userName.Text:=ini.ReadString('USER', 'Name', 'Anonim');
      MainForm.Combo.ItemIndex:=ini.ReadInteger('USER', 'Pol', 1);
      ini.Free;
    end;
```

Comment: I only need it to save the caption of an object selected. When the user selects a button it adds the caption to the stringlist which is then read to the ini file

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//save to ini file
ini.WriteString('Caption', 'Caption', MainForm.Caption);
end;

Comment: @VladIvchenko Does it need the MainForm part? I use INI files in my program and I have the following:
Ini.WriteString(Section, 'Caption', Table.Caption);

But this only works because I save an object in an objectlist rather than a string list. So rather than specifically storing the caption in the tstringlist i store all the objects data in a tobjectlist and then when i want to save to an ini file i only choose certain properties

Comment: You should *really* be using a `try .. finally` block for the lifetime of the `TIniFile` object. Especially for objects like this which could fail in their constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails to load the value back because you are trying to read it from the wrong area of the INI file.

You are writing the value to the `'LastClickedID'` entry of the `'Table'` section, which produces this INI data:

```
[Table]
LastClickedID=Value
```

But then you are trying to read the value from the `'LastClickedID'` entry of any section that begins with the `'LastClickedID'` prefix, not from the `'Table'` section that you previously wrote to. That would only work if the INI data looked more like this instead:

```
[LastClickedID]
LastClickedID=Value
```

Since that section does not exist in the INI, that is why your `LastClickedID` variable is always blank (if `LastClicked` is also blank to begin with).

You don't need to use `Ini.ReadSections()` in this example.  Just use `Ini.ReadString()` by itself with the proper `'Table'` section name, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadFile(const Filename : String);
var
  Ini : TMemIniFile;
  LastClickedID: string;

  procedure LoadReserve;
  var
    section : String;
  begin
    Section := 'Table';
    LastClickedID := Ini.ReadString(Section, 'LastClickedID', LastClicked);
  end;

begin
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(Filename);
  try
    LoadReserve;
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;

  ShowTable(LastClickedID);
end;
```

In general, you should be mirroring the opposite of whatever your `SaveToFile()` code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read this documentation and example [to use TMemIniFile and TIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_TIniFile_and_TMemIniFile). It should be helpful...

Here is my code :

```
Procedure TForm1.SaveToFile(Const Filename : String);
Var
  Ini : TIniFile;    
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(filename);      
  try
    Ini.WriteString('Table', 'LastClickedID', LastClicked);
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure TForm1.LoadFile(const Filename : String);
var
  Ini : TInifile;
  LastClickedID : String;    
begin    
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(Filename);
  try
    LastClickedID := Ini.ReadString('Table', 'LastClickedID', '');
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
  ShowTable(LastClickedID);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a general ini file utility object, which can read/write under the predefined key, the properties collected by a dictionary object. This is a flexible, reusable solution.
You can collect the clicked control captions into the dictionary and save the list at the end of your process. You should use a dictionary because a key/value pair needed for an ini file operation.

```
uses
    Generics.Collections
  , System.IniFiles
  ;

TIniFileUtility = class
  public
    class read( ini_ : TIniFile; keyName_ : string; props_ : TDictionary<string,string> );
    class write( ini_ : TIniFile; keyName_ : string; props_ : TDictionary<string,string> );
end;



class procedure TIniFileUtility.write( ini_ : TIniFile; keyName_ : string; props_ : TDictionary<string,string>);
var
  i : integer;
  key, value : string;
begin
  //... some input parameter checking
    for key in props_.keys do
    begin
      value := props_.Items[key];
      ini_.writeString( keyName_, key, value );
    end;
end;

procedure caller(Sender: TObject);
var
  ini : TIniFile;
  props : TDictionary<string,string>;
begin
  ini := TIniFile.create( 'c:\temp\defaults.ini' );
  try
    props := TDictionary<string,string>.Create;
    try
      props.Add( 'key1', 'stringValue' );
      props.Add( 'key2', intToStr( 2 ) );
      TIniFileUtility.write( ini, '\x\y\z\', props );
    finally
      props.Free;
      props := NIL;
    end;
  finally
    ini.Free;
    ini := NIL;
  end;
end;
```