# Replace String in Text-File (Lazarus)

Tags: string, replace, freepascal, lazarus

Recently I implemented a procedure to set the the Size of my tool by reading a line in a .txt-file. Now I want to expand on that by using a ComboBox to change the Size during run time. I have set up four different cases which all work fine. But since I want the tool size (which was changed during runtime) to be saved in that same .txt-file I want to replace that string after I chose a ComboBox-Case and read the .txt again to set the new size. I have started to recycle some code from another project but still need some help. Below you can see my code. I need some help in line 97 to properly replace the string or better delete the whole line and write a string to it:

```
unit Unit1;
 
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
 
interface
 
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;
 
type
 
  { TForm1 }
 
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
 
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    
    procedure ComboSetting();
 
  private
    sScreenSize:       String;
    Faktor:            extended;
 
  public
 
  end;
 
var
  Form1: TForm1;
 
const cMyFileName='..\Binaries\conf.ini';
 
implementation
 
{$R *.lfm}
 
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ComboBox1.Items.Clear;            
   ComboBox1.Items.Add('Size XL (3840 x 2160p)');        
   ComboBox1.Items.Add('Size L (2560 × 1440p');
   ComboBox1.Items.Add('Size M (1920 x 1080p');
   ComboBox1.Items.Add('Size S (1280 x 720p');
 
   ComboSetting;
end;
 
procedure TForm1.ComboSetting();
var
   MyFile:Text;
   Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6:String;
begin
   AssignFile(MyFile,cMyFileName);
   Reset(MyFile);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line1);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line2);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line3);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line4);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line5);
   ReadLn(MyFile,Line6);
 
   sScreenSize:=Line6;
 
   CloseFile(MyFile);
 
   if sScreenSize='size=XL' then
      begin
         Faktor:=1;
      end
   else if sScreenSize='size=L' then
      begin
         Faktor:=1.6;
      end
   else if sScreenSize='size=M' then
      begin
         Faktor:=2.4;
      end
   else if sScreenSize='size=S' then
      begin
         Faktor:=3.6;
      end;
 
   Width:=round(Screen.Width/Faktor);
   Height:=round(Screen.Height/Faktor);
end;
 
 
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of  //welcher Auswahltext (welches Item) wurde aktuell gewählt
    0: begin
            Faktor:=1;
            slMyFileStrings:=TStringList.Create;
               try
                  slMyFileStrings.LoadFromFile(cMyFileName);
                  //Replace Line6 with string'size=XL'
               finally
                  slMyFileStrings.Free;
            ComboSetting;
    end;
    1: begin
            Faktor:=2;
            ComboSetting;
    end;
    2: begin
            Faktor:=3;
            ComboSetting;
    end;
    3: begin
            Faktor:=4;
            ComboSetting;
    end;
  end;
end;
 
end.
```

I'm using FreePascal with the Lazarus IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save to an INI file delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854229/how-to-save-to-an-ini-file-delphi)

Comment: This sound promessing. Thank you very much!