# Delphi and UniDAC MySQL connect string

Tags: delphi, unidac

How can I make an ini file to connect TO mySQL databases. I'm using UniDAC comments from a Delphi 10.4 app.
I need help, I need the code

Comment: You can do it in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854229/how-to-save-to-an-ini-file-delphi

Comment: An important thing to pay attention to is that you may need to Encrypt values before writing in "ini" file and Decrypt when you want to read them. Otherwise everybody will be able to read connection info of your database.

Comment: You can find lot's of usefull examples to Encrypt/Decrypt strings like this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798188/delphi-simple-string-encryption